# Karate json path filter not working when trying to extract elements that meet some filter criteria in API response

Tags: api, testing, karate, gherkin

I am trying to filter my API response using JSON Path filter using Karate framework to extract a specific value that meets one of the condition using a value from a variable but I am not able to map variable properly, so my filter not working properly. I looked at the documentation and tried multiple ways but couldn't resolve this issue.

**Sample response JSON:**

````
  "slices": [
    {
      "id": 7591164138534052,
      "duration": {
        "value": 1675,
        "unit": "MINUTE"
      },
      "segments": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "segmentRefId": 23783268357325705
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "segmentRefId": 7591164138531002
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "segmentRefId": 7591164138532394
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "segments": [
    {
      "id": 23783268357325705,
      "departDateTime": "2019-10-05T19:50:00",
      "arrivalDateTime": "2019-10-06T14:25:00",
      "originAirport": "LAX",
      "destinationAirport": "LHR",
      "duration": {
        "value": 635,
        "unit": "MINUTE"
      },
      "marketingAirline": "BA",
      "operatingAirline": "AA",
      "flightNumber": "1509",
      "equipmentCode": "77W",
      "subjectToGovtApproval": false,
      "numOfStops": 0,
      "stops": []
    }
  ]
}```

I am using the below script where I am using variable 'originRefId':

* def originRefId = response.slices[0].segments[0].segmentRefId
* def origin = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.segments[?(@.id=='originRefId')]")
* print 'the value of Origin is:', origin


Expected results  LAX but I am getting an empty array.
17:42:15.119 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] the value of Origin is: [
]
````

Comment: you haven't simplified this. so try again and post a simpler example. you can start by removing all the parts of the JSON not relevant to this discussion. second: the `id` in your example anyway does not seem to match. third: you have to read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters

Comment: Updated. I did try to follow the documentation.  I am able to extract other values when I change key for the json filter. But as mentioned the above case doesn't work for some reason. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
* def originRefId = response.slices[0].segments[0].segmentRefId
* def segment = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.segments[?(@.id==" + originRefId + ")]")[0]
* def origin = segment.originAirport
* match origin == 'LAX'
```

Comment: @zsattar1224 yes I think you missed that for numbers, you don't need the string-quotes