# Is there a way to query a csv file in Karate?

Tags: csv, karate, data-driven-tests

I am looking for a similar functionality like [Fillo](https://codoid.com/fillo/) Excel API where we can do CRUD operations in an excel file using query like statements.

A select statement in a csv file is a great addition to the framework to provide more flexibility in test data driven approach testing.

Sample scenario: A test case that needs to have multiple data preparation of inserting records to database.

Instead of putting all test data in 1 row or 1 cell like this and do a string split before processing.

```
|TC-ID|FNAME               |LNAME               |
|TC-1 |FNAME1,FNAME2,FNAME3|LNAME1,LNAME2,LNAME3|
|TC-2 |FNAME4              |LNAME4              |
```

We can design our csv file like this below, when we have something like `* def data = read('Select * from persons.csv where TC-ID=TC-1')`

```
|TC-ID|FNAME |LNAME |
|TC-1 |FNAME1|LNAME1|
|TC-1 |FNAME2|LNAME2|
|TC-1 |FNAME3|LNAME3|
|TC-2 |FNAME4|LNAME4|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need. Karate can transform a CSV file into a JSON array in one line:

```
* def data = read('data.csv')
```

After that just use JsonPath or a "filter" operation to "query" for data (search the docs for more examples):

```
* def found = data.find(x => x['TC-ID'] === 'TC-1')
* def results = data.filter(x => x.FNAME.startsWith('A'))
```

Comment: Alright, I'll use that approach. thank you.

Comment: Peter, can you please share how can I use variables in filter expression?

* def filteredData = data.filter(x => x.TCID.match('TC-1'))

something like this filterColumn and filterValue
* def filteredData = data.filter(x => x.filterColumn).match(filterValue))

Comment: @Don I think the best thing is for you to talk to someone who knows JavaScript. but also see these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62873484/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/57291777/143475

Comment: Alright, just wanted to share that both of these are working just avoid hyphen in variable value (from TC-ID to TC_ID):
1. data.filter(x => x[FILTER_COLUMN].match(FILTER_VALUE))
2. karate.jsonPath(data, "$..[?(@."+FILTER_COLUMN+"=='"+FILTER_VALUE+"')]")