Read data from another data file dynamically by specific value in Karate Test?
Let say I have test below, could that be possible reference another data file like another examples table instead of defining the example table individually in each Scenario?
Feature: karate answers 2

Background:
  * url 'http://localhost:8080'

Scenario Outline: given circuit name, validate country
  Given path 'api/f1/circuits/<name>.json'
  When method get
  Then match $.MRData.CircuitTable.Circuits[0].Location.country == '<country>'

  Examples:
    | name   | country  |
    | monza  | Italy    |
    | spa    | Belgium  |
    | sepang | Malaysia |

I see we can use Dynamic Scenario Outline, but what if I have a csv file below, I want to read the file by the test_id.



test_id
name
country




1
monza
Italy


1
spa
Belgium


2
sepang
Malaysia




csv files are supported, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78673358/143475

@PeterThomas, could we filter out the result of the csv by the column test_id? For example the scenario 1 use test_id 1 data and scenario 2 use test_2 data?

yes, if you study the linked example it is a very complex one that shows how you can do filtering. see this also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70950171/143475
